# How can I compare a float number to a array whose componets are intervals in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to compare an array : [2, 4, 6, 9]
with a matrix (m*n) of intervals:

```
[[0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1]
 [1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2]
   .      .      .      .
   .      .      .      . 
   .      .      .      . ]
```

and the result would be a matrix (m*n) with 0 if the number is not in that interval or 1 in other case.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `numpy.digitize`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have control over the construction of the range matrix, you might consider using real ranges... Python has built-in `range` with start and stop parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is using nested list comprehension

```
data = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 5], [5, 10], [11, 20]]
check = [2, 4, 6, 9]

result = [any(1 if l <= y <= r else 0 for y in check) for l, r in data]
# [False, False, True, True, True, False]
```

If you would like to have 0 or 1 you can use following

```
result = [max(1 if l <= y <= r else 0 for y in check) for l, r in data]
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your ranges are implicitly sorted, you can simply check if your number is between the start element and the stop element:

```
for each element, e, in your input vector:
    for each range pair (low, high) in your interval matrix:
        if low <= e <= high; then
          true
        else 
          false
```

In Python:

```
def check_within_range(arr, mat):
    return [[low <= e <= high for e in arr] for (low, high) in mat]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return a matrix of booleans (which can easily be seen as 1 and 0). Hope this is what you'd like to achieve.

```
# m is the matrix
# a is the array
result = [[y in range(x[0], x[-1]) for y in a] for x in m]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, the `range` part escaped me. Thx.

Comment: Note that searching in `range` in O(log n), when you could do it in O(1).

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of solution.

```
x = [2,4,6,9]
m = [[0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1],[1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2]]
output = [[int(x[i] in y) for (i,y) in enumerate(line)] for line in m]
```

Comment: It still is not correct. If the range is [0,3], 2 will not be in that range according to your formulation.

Comment: why is not correct? If you see [0,3] as the interval of 2 elements (0 and 3), it is works. I anderstand the problem like this. The problem is not my answer but the definition of the problem.

Comment: OK, then it is wrong. The OP's list is supposed to contain bounds on an interval. Clearly 2 should fall in the range from 0 to 3.

Comment: Ok, It is how you see the problem, but it is not write. I am really sorry but it is not **clear**. Please say that the problem is not good written but don't say that my answer is wrong.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear; your answer is wrong.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interval

Comment: Ok, I am not agree with you. Just for information, the interval [1,3] on {1,3} is {1,3}. I stop it now, because you want just to be rigth and not the truth that it is not clear.